# How do I wire two 3-way switches when only a single 14/3 cable is going into each box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I'm trying to switch out my 2 Insteon 3-way smart switches (Insteon 2477S) with a pair of 3-way dimmer switches.  The 2 insteon switches were working fine, and are wired up in each box using a single 14/3 cable.  No other cables run into the boxes.  One switch had white/black/red all connected and the other switch had white/black connected with the red disconnected and capped off.  Ground attached at both ends as well.  As that stands, they were working fine to control 3 lights in my basement as expected of a 3 way switch.  Are these Insteon switch doing the 3 way control differently than typical switches do?

Wires were labeled on both original switches as:
Black/Line, Red/Load, White/Neutral.

I shut off power, disconnected everything (wires are built into the switch and color coded), and turned power back on to test where the "main" switch was.  Turns out both boxes have a hot black wire running to it.  So both boxes, had a black/white/red/ground with a hot black.

I bought a KASA 3-way dimmer kit (KS230 KIT), and from what I can tell, these won't work since they require 2 travelers, neutral and black load/line.  They call out specifically it requires a neutral wire.  Also, all instructions say that only the main switch should have a live black, and the satellite switch should have no live wires.  Many online videos confirmed that.  So I'm stumped as to why both sides have a live black wire, and why both sides only have a single cable running into it.

Is anyone familiar with this type of setup, or have suggestions how I can get a 3 way dimmer to work.  I don't require a wifi dimmer specifically, but I'd prefer something that doesn't require a hub.  I really just need a functional 3-way switch that can dim (even if it's only from one side).  Wifi is a bonus, Kasa is ideal since I have other Kasa devices in the house.

Thank you in advance, and here are some images that will hopefully help out.

Box 1 - all 3 wires connected
[image]

Box 2 - Black/White connected, red capped off
[image]

(New) Kasa Main Switch
[image]

(New) Kasa Satellite Switch
[image]

Comment: If there is only one cable or conduit coming into the box, you are almost certainly looking at a switch loop. Rewire the lamp so this is *only* a simple switch loop, with a neutral  so you can use those switches. Rewire so the other switch just has hot/neutral/ground going to it so the smart switch there has power but doesn't directly switch anything. Tie the two switches together at the programming level so the second serves as a remote for the first. See past questions about three-way, switch loops, and smart switches for more detail.

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't looked into Insteon's own line of dimmers?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - I have other Kasa devices in my home and they work great with Google Home, simple to use, plus I'm familiar with that ecosystem.  Insteon is also significantly more expensive and the selection of products is smaller.  So as I replace/upgrade, I'm trying to stick to all Kasa.

Comment: @keshlam - I will look into doing that.  I've read up on switch loops and 3 ways, but with them both combined on the circuit I may be punching above my weight class on that.  I did some further investigation and it appears that the box with all 3 wires connected will operate the lights fine (using the insteon) on it's own with the other switch disconnected.  But replacing the insteon switch where the red wire was capped off won't switch the lights on or off.  So to rewire as you explained, would I physically need to route new wire, or would what's existing work to do that?

Comment: What is the setup in the box for the light fixture? I suspect they may be using the less-common (but still valid) wiring where you join your two three-way wires in the fixture box.